# Exact Length regular expression on route in Express JS

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I'm trying to set a route in my app but I want that the URL parameter is exactly length 2 chars,  this is what I have :

```
app.all('/:lng{2}?',function (req, res, next) {
 // my code ...
});
```

but it doesn't work, my :lng parameter is not limited to exactly 2 chars and the code {2} it doesn't make any differences.

someone have a solution ? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [actual regular expression](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.METHOD) rather than a string:

```
app.all(/^\/(\w{2})?$/,function (req, res, next) {
 // my code ...
});
```

The parentheses introduce a capturing group, the value of which will be available in `req.params[0]`. Substitute `\w` for whatever makes sense in your situation.

Comment: I'd add some anchors in there as well, otherwise it becomes a substring match